# Getting Time from timestamp in R

Tags: r, time, time-series

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df<- structure(list(timeStamp = structure(c(1388308300, 1388308310, 
                                       1388308320, 1388308330, 1388308340, 1388308350, 1388308360, 1388308370, 
                                       1388308380, 1388308390), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
               Bid = c(NA, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 
                          15.2, 15.2), 
               Ask = c(NA, 15.05, 15.05, 15.05, 15.05, 15.05, 15.05, 15.05, 15.05, 15.05)), 
              .Names = c("timeStamp","Bid", "Ask"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I can extract the dates easily as:

```
df$dates <- as.Date(df$timeStamp)
```

However, I do not know how to get the times. I need this to filter the dataset by times independent of dates (e.g. `time> "06.00.00"`). There is no `as.Time()` function,

I tried:

```
strptime(df$timeStamp,format="%H:%M:%S")
```

and

```
as.POSIXct(df$timeStamp, format="%H:%M:%S")
```

but they don't work...

Comment: Please check the `dput`. It gives error

Comment: Your example gives me an "unexpected string constant"... could you please edit?

Comment: I edited, should work now

Comment: If you want to extract as string `format(as.POSIXct(df$timeStamp), '%H:%M:%S')`

Comment: Please expalin what you intend to do with the times. Possibly package chron yould be of help.

Comment: I need this to filter the dataset by times independent of dates (e.g. time> "06.00.00")

Comment: @Zhubarb Perhaps `xts` might be useful

Comment: @akrun, thank you - can you post your comment with `format` above as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(chron)
df$times <- times(format(df$timeStamp, '%H:%M:%S'))
df[df$times > times("10:12:00"),]
#             timeStamp  Bid   Ask    times
#4  2013-12-29 10:12:10 15.2 15.05 10:12:10
#5  2013-12-29 10:12:20 15.2 15.05 10:12:20
#6  2013-12-29 10:12:30 15.2 15.05 10:12:30
#7  2013-12-29 10:12:40 15.2 15.05 10:12:40
#8  2013-12-29 10:12:50 15.2 15.05 10:12:50
#9  2013-12-29 10:13:00 15.2 15.05 10:13:00
#10 2013-12-29 10:13:10 15.2 15.05 10:13:10
```